# Insert single and double quotes in a wordpress database

Tags: php, mysql, regex, wordpress

I'm trying to save some titles to a mysql database in wordpress allowing double and single quotes. So I want to be able to insert strings such as:

```
    A man's dog walked into the bar
    The "main reason" it does not work
    It's time to announce "The Show" in an hour
```

My code looks like such:

```
    $question_id = filter_var($_REQUEST['question_id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $feedback_correct = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9'\"?_\. !&-]+/","",sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['feedback_correct']));
    $feedback_incorrect = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9'\"?_\. !&-]+/","",sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['feedback_incorrect']));
    //preg_replace is to strip out any characters we dont want in the title like "<>|}{[]/"
    $data = array(
    'feedback_correct' => $feedback_correct,
    'feedback_incorrect' => $feedback_incorrect
    );

    $update_feedback = $eot_quiz->updateQuestion($data, $question_id);
```

And the updateQuestion function:

```
        public function updateQuestion($data = array(), $id = 0)
        {
        global $wpdb;
        $result = $wpdb->update(TABLE_QUIZ_QUESTION, $data, array('ID' => $id));
            if ($result === false) 
            {
                return false;
            } 
            else 
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

After the trip to the database, my strings look like:

```
    A man
```

*string is cut off after the single quotes

```
    The "main reason" it does not work
```

*look ok with double quotes

```
    It
```

*string is cut off after the single quote

How do I get these strings inserted correctly in the db? Thanks in advance.

Display Code:

```
     <?php
      $quiz_question = $eot_quiz->get_question_by_id($question_id);

      ?>
       <div class="bs">
         <div class="panel panel-default">
            <form method="POST" action="#">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h3 class="panel-title"><?= $quiz_question['quiz_question']?></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="feedback_correct">Feedback for correct answer</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="feedback_correct" placeholder="Correct Feedback" value='<?= $quiz_question['feedback_correct']?>'>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="feedback_incorrect">Feedback for incorrect answer</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="feedback_incorrect" placeholder="Incorrect Feedback" value='<?= $quiz_question['feedback_incorrect']?>'>
                </div>
                <input type='hidden' name='question_id' value="<?= $question_id ?>" />
                <input type='hidden' name='quiz_id' value="<?= $quiz_id ?>" />
                <input type='hidden' name='subscription_id' value="<?= $subscription_id ?>" />
                <input type='hidden' name='feedback' value="true" />
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Update Feedback</button>

        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer"><a href="/dashboard/?part=update_quiz_questions&question_id=<?= $question_id?>&quiz_id=<?= $quiz_id?>&subscription_id=<?= $subscription_id ?>" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Take me back to the Question</a><div style="clear:both"></div></div>
         </form>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: No, no bobby tables here. The `wpdb` code uses proper bind parameters.

Comment: I tried bobby tables:
$result = $wpdb->update(TABLE_QUIZ_QUESTION, $data, array('ID' => $id),array('%s','%s'));
same result

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of your `preg_replace()` method invocations. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: @O.Jones edited

Comment: Are you looking at the inserted values directly via a mysql prompt, though phpMyAdmin or something similar, or are you fetching and displaying the values in a script you wrote yourself too? Because then that might be just as relevant to look at... your update looks ok to me, `WPDB` should take care of escaping anything on the way to the db pretty much no matter what you throw at it...

Comment: @Mikk3lRo I'm fetching and displaying the values from the database in a text field.

Comment: Then you might be using single quotes around the value and forget to use `esc_attr($data_from_db);` when outputting it...? Can you add the display code?

Comment: esc_attr solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `esc_attr` any time you want something inside an elements attributes:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="feedback_correct" placeholder="Correct Feedback" value='<?php
//Always escape before echoing to an html attribute
esc_attr($quiz_question['feedback_correct']);
?>'>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the base class of `$wpdb`?  Find out its escape mechanism and use it

Or, use `addslashes()`.

Please don't try to use `preg_replace`, you may not handle all the characters that need escaping.  (It is more than just apostrophe and quote.)